# WordPress: Do not show tags if they are a subgroup of another tag

Tags: wordpress, tags, hierarchical-clustering

**Setting**

I have a huge set of posts (> 10.000) that are all equipped with varying numbers of tags per post. A typical post would have, eg, 3-4 tags like "washington, usa, travel, america", another one tags like "washington, city, architecture, usa".

With such a huge number of posts a problem arises: Very often, there is a tag ("usa") that is completely included in another tag ("america").

Completely included means that all posts belonging to "usa" also belong to "america" (but not the other way round). - This problem happens on several levels: Think of "america" being part of "world" or "washington" being part of "usa".

**Problem**

If you look at these tags, there is a logical cluster appearing: **washington** is part of **usa** is part of **america** is part of **world**. (**washington** is also part of **architecture** and part of **city**.) - so there are two hierarchies in regards to content.

Now I would like to show the user what WordPress calls a tag-archive, but with the highest level tags only. So in this case, it would be "world" and "city". When the user clicks "world", a new page is loaded presenting "america", "europe", "asia", etc. - Once we are down to a specificity that would return only, say, 100 posts at maximum (and not thousands like in the levels above), the selection/clustering-process would be stopped and I would show the user these posts.

(No, sorry, hierarchical categories, which would exactly do what I have just written, are not an option as these posts are automatically added and new clusters might pop up in the future.)

**Question**

How can I determine these kinds of clusters as efficient as possible?

A solution (code) is of course my preferred answer, but I am also happy, if one can point me into a direction that deals with this problem. Languages used in this project are PHP, SQL and Elastic Search.

Comment: But whats the issue with using hierarchical categories because **these posts are automatically added and new clusters might pop up in the future.** ?

Comment: @OmarTanti, I cannot use categories, because tagging is done by visitors and not by the post-authors themselves. So once interest pivots into another - currently non existing - main category, so does the site's focus. If I had stable categories, I would then have to add new main categories manually, which is exactly what I want to prevent with the auto-generation of these hierarchies by tags alone.

Comment: I think you can create more than one taxonomy (non-hierarchical in your case) eg tags-continent, tags-country, tags-city etc.. and users enter tags in each one of them separately. I dont know if this works for you but then you can first filter posts with tags-continent only, then with both tags-continent and tags-country etc.. I don't know if I understood your issue exactly but this is the only 'solution' that I could think of.

Comment: @OmarTanti, this would work, if I would know what kind of topics there are and how tags are related to each other, but I do not know this. This is fluid and can change anytime...